# Validate Column Data of excell sheet using ,Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Sheets (W1 and W2) and sheet W1 has 2 columns

```
Name        Gender
.....................
OM          Male
Neha        Female
```

and sheet W2 has 2 columns

```
Value          Age 
....................
Male           30
Female         25
Others         50
```

I want to validate data of sheet W1, Gender column. When fill column value check  all value in Gender column should be match from w2 sheet Value column or we can say only value column of w2 sheet data fill in Gender column in W1 sheet. how it possible using macro on before save Event.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the before save event?  If you are asking how to validate the gender column of worksheet W1 then I do not understand what you want validated.